# How to call function on 'Enter' press in TextInput - React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to make Search Bar. I want user to type something in `TextInput` and when user press 'Enter' I want to call my function.

```
<TextInput
//here when user press enter call function()
style={styles.searchStyle}
allowFontScaling={false}
placeholder="Search" 
onChangeText={(val) => {setSearch(val)}}
/>
```

I tried `onSubmitEditing` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' 
import {TextInput} from 'react-native'

const Trial = () => {
    const onSubmitted = () => {
        console.log('Submitted')
      }
return(
    <TextInput
//here when user press enter call function()
// style={styles.searchStyle}
allowFontScaling = {false}
placeholder = "Search" 
onSubmitEditing = {() => onSubmitted()}

/>
)
}

export default Trial
```

onSubmitEditing it works fine, I hope it would be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mutiline={true} in TextInput like `<TextInput multiline={true} />` onSubmitEditing will not work, instead it will move to nextLine.

I am doing a workaround, so basically I check if user entered next line, if so, call submit function and dismiss keyboard, you can import {Keyboard} from react-native

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(txt) => {
        if (/\n/.test(txt)) {
         //call submit function here
          Keyboard.dismiss()
          return
        } else {
          //do something here
        }
        
      }} />
```